# JQuery/JavaScript For Spinning Disc

Tags: javascript, jquery

I feel like a complete idiot.  I spent about four hours making this script work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryrotate.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jQueryRotate.js"></script>

<a href=""><img src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/humano2/16x16/emblems/emblem-cd.png" id="image"><span id="spin">Spin</span></a>




   $("#spin").rotate({
    bind: {
        mouseover: function () {
            $("#image").rotate({
                animateTo: 180
            })
        },
        mouseout: function () {
            $("#image").rotate({
                animateTo: 0
            })
        }
    }

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8LV3p/3673/

Now for the life of me, I can not figure out how to use it on my website.  I have tried to research how to do this, but since I have no knowledge of JavaScript or JQuery, I have no idea what to search for.  Please help!

Comment: What do you actually want, please explain.

Comment: I don't understand the question. It is working in the fiddle. What do you mean "i can not figure out how to use it on my website"

Comment: Looks like it's working to me, what's wrong?

Comment: If your code is working fine then copy the code and paste inside the html head tag. Then preview it.

Comment: Yes, include jQuery! Look at the left panel on jsFiddle... it already sets up jQuery for you. But for your website you'll need to add your own.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){...});` Put your code inside a document.ready

Comment: you need to put your js within script tags too

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are going to want to include this in your .html file, most likely between the `<body>` tag (you might want to put the jQueryRotate.js script in your `<head>` tag so that it is loaded first):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryrotate.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jQueryRotate.js"></script>

<a href=""><img src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/humano2/16x16/emblems/emblem-cd.png" id="image"><span id="spin">Spin</span></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#spin").rotate({
    bind: {
     mouseover: function () {
      $("#image").rotate({
            animateTo: 180
      })
    },
    mouseout: function () {
      $("#image").rotate({
              animateTo: 0
      })
    }
  }

});
</script>
```

The `<script type="text/javascript">` tag in an HTML document tells the browser to execute anything inside as javascript.

Is this what you were asking?

Comment: Yes - and user666 is right - you need to include jQuery. This will pull the latest version from google: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: He got it 3 times :p overdose Jqeury i think :p

Answer (score 1):

is it possible you forgot to link to Jquery ?

```
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

Full page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My page</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryrotate.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jQueryRotate.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#image").rotate({
    bind: {
        mouseover: function () {
            $(this).rotate({
                animateTo: 360
            })
        },
        mouseout: function () {
            $(this).rotate({
                animateTo: 0
            })
        }
    }

});



$("#spin").rotate({
    bind: {
        mouseover: function () {
            $("#image").rotate({
                animateTo: 360
            })
        },
        mouseout: function () {
            $("#image").rotate({
                animateTo: 0
            })
        }
    }

});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<style>
#image {
    margin-bottom:-5px;
}
a {
    color:red;
}
#spin {
    margin-left:10px;
}
</style>

<a href=""><img src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/humano2/16x16/emblems/emblem-cd.png" id="image"><span id="spin">asdfasdfasdgt</span></a>
</body>    
</html>
```

Comment: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryrotate.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jQueryRotate.js">


$("#spin").rotate({
    bind: {
        mouseover: function () {
            $("#image").rotate({
                animateTo: 180
            })
        },
        mouseout: function () {
            $("#image").rotate({
                animateTo: 0
            })
        }
    }

});
</script>

Comment: This is what I have in my header.

Comment: is a public webpage can you give the link, me might be faster tot help, and you got jquery ? not forgot $(document).ready(function(){.....}); ?

Comment: You have 3 times Jquery in your header!

1. <script type="text/javascript" src="aom/js/jquery.js"></script> 2. <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
3.             
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

Comment: I'm a complete newbie to Javascript and JQuery.  I think I'm going to bury my face in a book for a couple weeks.  I still can't get it to work.

Comment: Lol billy give me some time, wait a second, i'm at work everyhing is slower here :)

Comment: first of all, i see you don't have a body tag, correct ? something like <body> ?

Comment: I just put the <body> tag in.  I didn't notice it.

Comment: I don't know why two doctypes are showing up.  I'm working with a template I've never used before and the code is sloppy.

Comment: There is alot wrong but lets us focus on the disc :)
yes i see it, next: remove this line: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  line 15 in sourch looking

Than remove: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> line 1, 

Than:
on 8 <script type="text/javascript" src="aom/js/jquery.js"></script>

Comment: Than this all out: <script type="text/javascript" src="aom/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="aom/js/shop.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="aom/js/lightbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" href="aom/js/lightbox/lightbox1/colorbox.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> &nbsp; this  links are in the <body>..</body> part move them out ;)

Comment: Yeah hmmm, let the doctypes be, np, try to remove what you can, we are almost there

Comment: Im going home now, but the <script>the code for the spinning</script> in the head tag!

Comment: hmm still trying mate i will take a look tomorrow ;)

Comment: Okay.  Thank you for your help and I apologize for being incompetent.

Comment: Got it!!!!!  Had to clean up all the code and it works now.  Thank you everyone for your help.

Comment: yes i told you to clean up! gj!

edit: i like people who try long for stuff, makes us all bether!

Comment: I'm OCD when it comes to coding and my websites.  Was up till 2 in the morning the other day trying to figure that script out.  lol

Comment: Okay.  So now I can't get it to work where I want it to.  If you visit my site, I want it to work where the bullets are supposed to go.  I don't know why it's not working!

Answer (score 1):

**A working example of the codes combined is:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html ">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryrotate.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jQueryRotate.js"></script>

<style>
#image {
    margin-bottom:-5px;
}
a {
    color:red;
}
#spin {
    margin-left:10px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<a href=""><img src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/humano2/16x16/emblems/emblem-cd.png" id="image"><span id="spin">asdfasdfasdgt</span></a>
</body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#image").rotate({
    bind: {
        mouseover: function () {
            $(this).rotate({
                animateTo: 360
            })
        },
        mouseout: function () {
            $(this).rotate({
                animateTo: 0
            })
        }
    }
});

$("#spin").rotate({
    bind: {
        mouseover: function () {
            $("#image").rotate({
                animateTo: 360
            })
        },
        mouseout: function () {
            $("#image").rotate({
                animateTo: 0
            })
        }
    }

});
});
</script>
</html>
```

***Save it in .html file. See it rotate. :)***

It's best to wrap your javascript in a document ready function in this case:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Your javascript codes here.
});
```

For a jquery plugin, you always need to include jQuery in your script.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably aren't waiting for the DOM to initialize if you put this in your header. Wrap that inside a

```
$(function() { // Short for $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#image").rotate({
        bind: {
            mouseover: function () {
                $(this).rotate({
                animateTo: 360
                })
            },
            mouseout: function () {
                $(this).rotate({
                    animateTo: 0
                })
            }
        }

    });

    $("#spin").rotate({
        bind: {
            mouseover: function () {
                $("#image").rotate({
                    animateTo: 360
                })
            },
            mouseout: function () {
                $("#image").rotate({
                   animateTo: 0
                })
            }
        }

    });
});
```